# Microphone Boost not available anymore in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

For many years, I used to have the option to enable/control a "Microfone Boost" level in the Windows Microphone Settings under the "Levels" tab:

[image: Windows Microfone Levels]

However, for some time now, that Microfone Boost slider has disappeared. This applies to all my various sound cards, both on-board and several external USB sound cards. Furthermore, the issue also occurs on a laptop which has completely different hardware from my main PC.

There are some typical instructions on the web on how to supposedly restore Microfone Boost, e.g. [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-get-the-microphone-boost-option-in-windows-10/). I have tried all of these several times, but without success.

Is there any other way to re-enable Microfone Boost?

Comment: There are third-party tools such as Voice Meeter; see https://www.groovypost.com/howto/boost-microphone-levels-in-windows-10/

Comment: wow, that's an awesome application, thanks